# Receive data per month with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'am trying to create a morrisJS line chart that shows data per month.
So i get the data per month like this:

```
        $intakes = Intakes::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2018)
        ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 1)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 2)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 3)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 4)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 5)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 6)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 7)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 8)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 9)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 10)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 11)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 12);
        })
        ->get();
```

But that would return all the records, in the range from month 1 to 12. But what i want is the data per month, can this be achieved apart from just creating multiple variables like this ?

```
          $intakesMonth1 = Intakes::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2018)
            ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 1)
            ->get();

          $intakesMonth2 = Intakes::whereYear('created_at', '=', 2018)
            ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', 2)
            ->get();
```

I hope that i'm clear enough and someone knows a better solution.

Comment: Almost 5 years later, can't believe i even dared to ask this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an Eloquent solution, use `whereMonth()`:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 13; $++) {
    $intakes[$i] = Intakes::whereMonth('created_at', $i)->get();
}
```

You can also, get all intakes for the year and then use `where()` Laravel Collections method to get intakes for one month only:

```
$oneMonthData = $collection->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::parse($someDateString)->startOfMonth())->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::parse($someDateString)->endOfMonth());
```

Comment: Thats a smarter way yeah, but i want them to get them in ajax and then i would have to return 12 variables. But this is definitely a better solution then not looping through them.

Comment: @frogeyedman it will give you one array with 12 collections in it which you can convert to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $intakes = Intakes::whereDate('created_at', '<=', '01-01-2018 00:00:00')->whereDate('created_at', '<=', '01-02-2018 23:59:59')->get();
```